# How to bind a value to a variable in a programmatically generated Linq Expression

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, c#-5.0

I am trying to programmatically generate an expression tree (that will eventually get used in Linq-to-entity framework).

I can get the query to work just fine with one exception - it does not parametrize the query - which I want for Sql Server query plan reuse.

I read that in order for the generated sql to be parametrized, the expression needs to compare based on a variable.  However, I cannot figure out how to assign the value to the variable in the expression tree.  If I just use `Expression.Constant`it works (but is not parametrized).

So basically:

```
public Expression<Func<T, bool>> FooEquals<T>(
    Expression<Func<T, int>> propertyExpression, int value)
{
    ParameterExpression param = propertyExpression.Parameters.Single();

    int targetValueForEqualityComparison = 9;

    //There's some "special sauce" here which is why I don't 
    //use propertyExpression directly
    var body = Expression.Property(param, GetPropertyName(propertyExpression)); 

    //If I just use Expression.Constant, it works, but doesn't parametrize.
    //var equalExpression = ParameterExpression.Equal(body,
    //   Expression.Constant(targetValueForEqualityComparison, typeof(int)));

    var variable = Expression
                   .Variable(typeof(int), "targetValueForEqualityComparison");

    var assigned = Expression.Assign(variable, 
            Expression.Constant(targetValueForEqualityComparison, typeof(int)));

    //throws InvalidOperaitonException: "The parameter was not bound in the 
    //specified Linq to Entities query expression
    var equalExpression = ParameterExpression.Equal(body, variable); 

    //throws NotSupportedException: "Unknown LINQ expression of type 'Assign'.
    var equalExpression = ParameterExpression.Equal(body, assigned); 

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalExpression, param);
}
```

How do I properly bind a value to the variable expression so that Linq-to-EntityFramework will parametrize the query?

Comment: I checked out what kind of expression is generated when you reference a free variable in a Linq expression and, as with non-expression lambdas, it generates a class, stores the value in it and uses a FieldExpression containing a ConstantExpression containing a reference to an instance of that generated class to access the value. Perhaps that's what the SQL generator uses to detect parameters? Do you know how to work from that?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Thanks for the hint. That's all a bit new to me. This is the first time I've actually done a "free variable" as you called it.  If it's a generated class, how to I get a FieldExpression to its instance variable (if I understand what you're saying correctly)?

Comment: Does it really worth all that trouble. Looks like it's a static parameterized query. Why don't you just write the query and use a closure over a variable?

Comment: I'm sure you've used free variables if you've ever used lambda functions. Free variables are variables that are not arguments (or local variables) to the current function, but reference a variable from an outer scope. The `id` variable in my example below is used as a free variable in the first query.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Because `int targetValueForEqualityComparison = 9;` is actually a bit more complicated then shown here, and GetPropertyName has some extra behavior that prevents me from doing a compile time lambda expression.  In some ways it's an attempt to make up for EntityFramework's lack of type converters (as of version 5).

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Ah, I guess I was just unfamiliar with the term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and tried it out because I was curious. The following seem to result in identical SQL, at least when used with Linq-to-SQL (which LINQPad does more readily than EF). I'd imagine it should work just the same with EF though.

Seems like a pretty convoluted way to just pass an integer in, but because this is what the compiler generates for a plain lambda function, I guess this is what the SQL generator looks for.

```
// Given this class, which is equivalent to the compiler-generated class
class Holder {
    public int AnInteger;
}

int id = 1;

// You get the same SQL with a plain lambda function

var query = db.Items.Where(i => i.Id == id);

// or with a handwritten expression:

var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "i");

var paramHolder = new Holder { AnInteger = id };

// essentially, (i) => i.Id == paramHolder.AnInteger
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(arg, "Id"),
        Expression.Field(
            Expression.Constant(paramHolder), "AnInteger")),
    arg);

// the SQL this translates to is equivalent to that of the first query
var query2 = db.Items.Where(lambda);
```